# Paw Oauth2 Implicit Grant Flow: Invalid State in authorization response

Tags: paw-app

I have setup an authenticated endpoint that requires Slack signin via Oauth2. I have a web front-end that works great -- I can authenticate via Slack and get a token from my callback method (via JSON in the response).

[image]

If I try to implement the same flow in Paw, I see an error, "Invalid State in authorization response". From my server logs, I can see that the callback url is being hit and that the JSON is being returned, but Paw errors out and I can't inspect the response.

I'm trying to capture the JWT via "Response Parsed Body -> JSON"
[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the paw print:
https://paw.pt/ewvrJX0L

NOTE: Authorization Grant flow doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the server is not returning a `state` parameter as expected by the OAuth 2 spec. Some servers do not and most client libraries are deliberately accepting the response nevertheless.

Paw can ignore the `state` parameter and accept the server response if you uncheck the box **"Strict Mode: Perform additional checks on the response"**.

[image: Disable "Strict Mode" in Paw for OAuth 2]

This should help solve the problem in your case.